# How to find elephant with the lowest value in object

Tags: javascript

Hello I have a question how can I find elephant with the lowest value from object? I need to find elephant with the value of "minimum" variable. I mean I want to get the whole object.

```
 let numberOfElephants = 6;
let massOfElephants = [2400, 2000, 1200, 2400, 1600, 4000];
let startOrder = [1, 4, 5, 3, 6, 2];
let endOrder = [5, 3, 2, 4, 6, 1];
    
    
      
    
        const elephantObject = [];
          startOrder.forEach((order, i) => {
            elephantObject.push({ [order]: massOfElephants[i] });
          });
        
        for (let i = 0; i < numberOfElephants; i++) {
            for (let j = 0; j < numberOfElephants; j++) {
 const indexOfCorrect = proposedOrder.findIndex(
          (num) => num === endOrder[j]
        );
        const itemAtGivenOrder = startOrder[indexOfCorrect];
            
                const [value] = Object.values(elephantObject[i]);
                const [valueOfStarter] = Object.values(elephantObject[startOrder[i]]);
                const minimum = Math.min(
                  elephantAtGivenCorrectIndex[itemAtGivenOrder],
                  value
                );
```

Comment: It appears like your code example is missing a few different arrays. Could you please update your question to include them?  Example of what's missing:  massOfElephants, numberOfElephants, and elephantAtGivenCorrectIndex.

Comment: Also, when you run your javascript example, what is the output that you get? Can you include that with your question, and then point out what's wrong with that, or where do you want to see the improvements.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing at the intended content of `massOfElephants` here:

```js
let startOrder = [1, 4, 5, 3, 6, 2];
let massOfElephants = [100, 200, 500, 2, 8, 9000]

const elephantObject = [];
startOrder.forEach((order, i) => {
  elephantObject.push({
    [order]: massOfElephants[i]
  });
});

let leastMassyElephant = Math.min(...massOfElephants)

let output = elephantObject.filter(item => {
  return item[Object.keys(item)[0]] === leastMassyElephant
})

console.log(output)
```

Comment: I mean I want that but elephantObject, not arrays, I just need that object in my algorithm, I cut so much code. So I have value 1200 and I want to find object with that value.

Comment: The above returns the object with that value (assuming 1200 is the smallest elephant) in the same format that your `elephantObject` uses.  It just doesn't bother constructing objects for all the other elephants, because that's not necessary here.

Comment: I mean the only problem is that output does not have startOrder id as a key but just 2.

Comment: You're right, it looks like I missed what startOrder was doing there and based it on the index position inside the `mass` array.  I'll fix

Comment: OK, it's still easier to find the smallest elephant by just looking at the `mass` array, but now it constructs the whole object taking `startOrder` into account before returning an object